# Form passing variables but not their entered values

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have inherited some broken code but I'm not sure where the problem is. The code is a hyperlink (.control_button) which opens a form(#convert-form) in a lightbox . This then has a button (#print-button) which redirects to a php file (convert-tpl.php), passing fields from the form.

Using XDebug I can see that the variable 'testVariable' is in the $_GET array when it is passed to convert-tpl.php, but it is always set to 10, even when I change it to something else. My guess is that this is because the jQuery code is building the URL with the parameters when the page loads, so it doesn't pick up any entries in the form?

```
<div class="control_button"><a href="#convert-form" class="convert-link">Terms &amp; Conditions Print</a></div>

<div id="convert-form" style="display:none;">
            <h2>Print Terms &amp; Conditions</h2>
         <p>Fill out the form below to populate additional information in the terms and condition form. Then hit print to print a copy of the terms and conditions</p>
        <form action="phpscripts/convert.tpl" method="get" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" name="instructor_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['USER_ID']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
            <div class="price-details left">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Price Details</legend>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="prices_hour">1 Hour:</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="testVariable" value="10"/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <a id="print-button" href="phpscripts/convert-tpl.php" class="big-button button-link">Print</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".convert-link").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
        });
        jQuery('#print-button').printPage({
            url: jQuery('#print-button').attr('href')+'?'+jQuery('#convert-form form').serialize()
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try wrapping your `jQuery('#print-button').printPage({...})` with a `jQuery('#print-button').on(‘click’, function(){…})`, so that it doesn’t `serialize()` your form until you click print

Comment: That URL gets generated straight on away on page load, which is why only the default value is used. You need to rebuild the code to build the URL when you press the button instead.

Comment: I say that `value` of `testVariable` is plain static html. There is definetly some code missing, that is needed to successfully update `testVariable` on say page reload. And the problem it's not just building url the correct way.

Comment: I think I'm almost there. I changed the jQuery code to the following and it is passing the variable. Now the only problem is that the `#print-button` needs to be pressed twice. My issue is that I don't really understand what `printPage()` is doing:

   `jQuery('#print-button').on('click', function(){ 
    jQuery('#print-button').printPage({
     url: 'phpscripts/convert-tpl.php?'+jQuery('#convert-form form').serialize() 
    });
   });`

Answer (score 0):

Just putting @Sean code in action:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".convert-link").fancybox({
    maxWidth: 800,
    maxHeight: 600,
    fitToView: false,
    width: '70%',
    height: '70%',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none'
});
// use on function
$('#print-button').on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).printPage({
        url: jQuery('#print-button').attr('href') + '?' + jQuery('#convert-form form').serialize()
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this (see my comment above). The values are now passed, but for some reason with this code the #print-button needs to be pressed twice. Any ideas greatly appreciated.